# Could Not Find SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.0"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I debug the UWP apps by using Xamarin in Visual Studio 15 Preview 2 ,

the error display as below :

**Could not find SDK "Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime, Version=1.0"**

Comment: The Preview build has a feedback button for you to send such feedback. Nobody guarantees it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Do you also run VS 2015? Can you check what version of framework(s) you have got at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime\

If you have only 1.1 then it must be the installer which overwrote your folder. Try running a repair on your visual studio and you should be able to fix this.

Comment: Had the same issue as "Cheah" (using VS15 had removed v1). And repairing 2015 solved my problem. Excellent suggestion Jebarson!